# Need to disable TinyMCE default create an anchor tag when pasting a raw URL

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I've got TinyMCE installed on frontend of my wordpress website…it's separate from the default Wordpress version, however, I need it to NOT turn raw URLs into anchor tags because it screws up Wordpress's ability to then oEmbed it. I have it installed on a form where users can submit articles in the frontend (not Dashboard). Is there a way to disable this? I thought convert_urls: false would to the job, but it's not meant for that. I've looked for over two hours now and cannot find a suitable answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

well, usually it is not such a good practice to include 2 versions of the same script ..
at any rate - 
I do not know specifically about TinyMCE, but  you can use str_replace () php function (or preg_replace() ) to repair just about anything (if it is a string ..)

Comment: krembo99, thanks for the reply. I actually figured this out via the TinyMCE forum. It was as simply removing an option 'autolink' option from plugins parameter :) However, now I have a new issue…the editor is not working at all :( http://seeseemedia.com/testing-tinymce/